# How to add cyrillic text to AVFrame or IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, libav

Latin text can be easily added by means of cvPutText(), but I need to add cyrillic text to IpImage (or AVFrame, it doesn't matter).
Could you please help me? Thank you!